# Converting string into mathematical function in Tcl

Tags: regex, dictionary, split, tcl

Let's say I have a string, maybe "Enable && Signal" for simplicity's sake.

I'd like to convert this string to standard && operations in tcl, such that Enable && Signal would return   0 if any of the value is false and 1 only when both are true.

Is there an easy way to do this, As for my case i would need a generic method where the number of arguments can be any and perform logical/relational operations like && || == <= > != etc

Any help and insights would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

I initially tried to split the arguments into conditions list and data list but could not handled the precedence of operations. Like == need to be done first and later && operations for n^n combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that in your example, Enable and Signal are Tcl variables. So, all that would be needed to be able to pass the string to `expr` is to prepend a '$' to all identifiers. That can be done with `regsub` as follows:

```
set str "Enable && Signal"
regsub -all {\m[A-Za-z]\w*\M} $str {$&} expr
set result [expr $expr]
```

Due to the \m\M, This will properly leave numbers like 1e3 alone. But this method falls short if you also want to be able to use functions, like `sin(x)`. If that is also a requirement, a negative lookahead may help:

```
set str "sin(x) * cos(y)"
regsub -all {\m[A-Za-z]\w*\M(?!\()} $str {$&} expr
puts $expr
```

This produces: `sin($x) * cos($y)`

Comment: This is one of the few cases where an expression must not be braced.

Comment: If things are much more complex than that, you're probably best building a parser and code generator.